# How to deploy war file to Tomcat from Jenkins without using plugin

Tags: java, jenkins, tomcat

I want to deploy from my Jenkins to Tomcat without using this "Deploy to container" plugin .

So I am thinking of a Tomcat REST API to deploy a war file. The Tomcat and the Jenkins are on different servers.

Maybe it is enough to just copy the file to the webapps folder ? But then I still have to deploy it meaning to start it . Right ?

Honestly I have not found any REST API to deploy to Tomcat so far. The problem is to make the .war file available .

Comment: Just write a script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `Jenkins`, you can use a `bash script` to transfer the `.war` file to your `Tomcat` `webapps` directory (the code is the same if you work with a `pipeline`).

First, stop the Tomcat

```
ssh tomcat@tomcat '${TOMCAT_BIN_PATH}shutdown.sh'
```

Then, copy the war to the `webapps` directory of your `Tomcat`

```
scp -r -p jenkins@jenkins:path/to/war/file.war tomcat@tomcat:path/to/webapp/
```

After that, you have to start the `Tomcat` and the `.war` will be deployed automatically

```
ssh tomcat@tomcat '${TOMCAT_BIN_PATH}startup.sh'
```

---

If you are using `Maven`, I suggest you to take a look at `tomcat-maven-plugin`, you can find it [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.maven). You can deploy the war file with the following command:

```
mvn -B -P deploy-profile-from-pom-xml tomcat7:deploy-only
```

An example of implementation can be found [here](https://www.baeldung.com/tomcat-deploy-war#Deploy)

---

**UPDATE**

If you want `Tomcat` to delay the `webapps` directory checking, you can add `backgroundProcessorDelay` to your `server.xml` configuration

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" backgroundProcessorDelay="15">
```

Tomcat will only check for a new `.war` every 15 seconds with this code for instance.

Comment: Thanks. But do I really need to stop entire tomcat ??

Comment: Nope, it's just a preference. I prefer to do it because like that I know the user wont do anything during the installation process.

Comment: Ok. But you have to consider all the other apps will be shutdown during that time. This is horror . Just for installing a new app . In my opinion this is to much

Comment: I will copy the war file to webapps folder. In that point I agree with you. But then how can I register my new app so it can be accessed ?

Comment: If Tomcat is already started, it will automatically detect the new .war file and deploy it.

Comment: just by copying to webapps folder ? Are you sure ?

Comment: Yes, but you have to enable the functionnality if its not working for you, in the `server.xml` with `<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">`. For me, it was already enable by default (for you it should too).

Comment: Yeah cool. In my case it is also enabled. Wow . Pretty easy  :-)

Comment: Yep, don't forget to accept the anwser and vote up if it's ok for you :)

Comment: Yeah. But that also means that TomCat checks this folder basically every second . Or maybe there is a way to set a Listener to Linux .

Comment: You can modify the delay, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Before doing the scp  I want to delete the war file in webapps folder. Honestly I do not know what happens if I copy a file which already existis to webapps folder.  This is my code to delete war file in webapps folder: 1. ssh username@server
2. password
3. sudo su
4. docker exec -it d71a17118be bash
5. cd webapps
6. rm -rf proxy*

Comment: What if I overwrite existing file with scp . Will Tomcat notice this and restart this app ??

Comment: When copying WAR files directly to the `webapps` folder on a running Tomcat a race condition occurs: Tomcat can deploy the new file **before** the transfer is complete. Therefore you need: 1. either _"copy"_ the file atomically (e.g. move it from another folder in the same filesystem) or 2. use Tomcat Manager (or perform the `tryAddServiced/removeServiced` calls on the JMX bean `Catalina:type=Deployer,host=<hostname>`).

Comment: This is a really good point. In case tomcat would deploy a war file which has only be 50% copied would really be bad in a production environment

Comment: what do you think about this . Wouldn't this be much easier than all the scp stuff https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/manager-howto.html

Comment: Yes, you can also use that. It's a solution used by my suggestion of the `maven` plugin  `tomcat-maven-plugin`. But is it easier? it's a matter of personnal choice or constraint I think. Both solution will do the work.